# DataFrame: How to add a column whose values are a unique count of another column?

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a data set of online sale orders which contains data on the colors of products.
I wanted to create a column which gives the unique number of colors in one order.
I wrote this code:

```
df['colors_in_basket']= df.groupby('Order_number')['Colors'].transform('count')
```

However the above yields a result which counts all colors within one order and returns it across every row in that order.

I tried using this:

```
df['colors_in_basket']= df.groupby('Order_number')['Colors'].transform('unique')
```

but I got the following error:

*ValueError: 'unique' is not a valid function name for transform(name)*

What would be the solution to reach my goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.nunique.html), add `'n'`:

```
df['colors_in_basket']= df.groupby('Order_number')['Colors'].transform('nunique')
```